# Is it possible to set PyCharm to open a project on a remote server?

Tags: pycharm

Say I have my code on a remote server, is it possible to have PyCharm SSH into that server and pull the files from a specified directory? I see that I can set up my interpreter to be from the remote server but I would like it for files to be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Use the Remote Host bar to configure a remote connection (for instance, if you are using AWS EC2, use the SFTP, public IP PEM file option and set the deployment path to be the project root). After this is configured you can right click and freely deploy to/download from the remote server.